# Css Text positioning is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi this is my code [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VgBPg/1/). My text positioning is not working properly.Right now the default text-align is right and it is working fine but when i am changing into to center or left then it is not positioning correctly what i am missing in my code?

```
#headline1Txt, #headline2Txt, #headline3Txt
{
  text-align:right;
    position: relative; 
    top:60px;
    left: -160px;
    width: 140px;

}
```

Comment: it is working fine at my side on chrome browser. Which browser you are using?

Comment: It is positioning correctly for me on both chrome browser and firefox. What exactly is happening for you?

Comment: ok i will explain it again right now   text-align:right; which is fine and text is animation to the right but i change it to   text-align:left; then it is adding some padding and it is not in the extreme left . is it clear now?

Comment: Can you put the JSFiddle of the non working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VgBPg/11/)

Script

```
function bannerAnimation(){
    //Jquery Animation
    $("#headline1Txt").animate({ left: "20" }, 700, function () {
        $("#headline1Txt").animate({ left: "0", right:"0" }, 350);
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#headline2Txt").animate({ left: "20" }, 700, function () {
            $("#headline3Txt").animate({ left: "20" }, 700, function () {
                $("#headline3Txt").animate({ left: "0", right:"0" }, 350);
            });
            $("#headline2Txt").animate({ left: "0", right:"0" }, 350);
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

CSS

```
#headline1Txt, #headline2Txt, #headline3Txt
{
    text-align:center;
    position: relative; 
    top:60px;
    left: -160px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: it is not animating properly. Your positions are fine but not the original animation

Comment: thanks Rohith can you tell me what i was doing wrong?

Comment: Please explain what the problem is and how your solution fixes it

Comment: In the CSS part, I have changed `text-align:right` to `text-align:center` and set width to `auto`.

Comment: In the script part, I have added positioning elements inside animate function `left: "0", right:"0"` which centers the element.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for: **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/VgBPg/7/)**

**CSS:**

```
#headline1Txt, #headline2Txt, #headline3Txt {
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    width: 140px;
    top:60px;
}
```

Comment: thanks kiran but i am not looking for this my alignment is having problem. By default i am using right and it is animation to extreme right but if i change it to left then it will add some padding or margin and will not animate to extreme left

Comment: @user3718016 do you want this? [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/VgBPg/9/)